# ASP.NET Bootstrap 4 Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination, webforms, asprepeater

I used pagination as described in this [article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-MySql-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
        CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "page_enabled" : "page_disabled" %>'
        OnClick="Page_Changed" OnClientClick='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "return false;" : "" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

This is link to [Demo](https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/999/)

I want to customize the pagination style by using bootstrap 4 pagination class

This is what i did but the current page is not highlighted

```
<ul class="pagination"> <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="page-item">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                    CssClass="page-link"
                    OnClick="Page_Changed" OnClientClick='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "return false;" : "" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater></ul>
```

How can i use BOTH `CssClass="page-link"` AND `CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "active" : "disabled" %>'`

Comment: Your link to article is not working. Please, fix it.

Comment: sorry, i have fixed it

Comment: Did you try `CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "active page-link" : "disabled page-link" %>'`?

Comment: no, i will try it now

Comment: Let me know. If it will work I'll write the answer.

Comment: yes,thanks, write it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine more classes by separating them by space. Example below.

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
        CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "active page-link" : "disabled page-link" %>'
        OnClick="Page_Changed" OnClientClick='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "return false;" : "" %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```